# Separating paging, sorting and filtering

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sorting, filtering, paging

In my ASP.NET MVC application I have a service that had a method for paging, sorting and filtering of Vehicle Makes:

```
     public class VehicleService : IVehicleService
 {
     private readonly DbContext _context;

     public VehicleService(DbContext context)
     {
         _context = context;
     }

       public async Task<IPagedList<VehicleMake>> GetVehicleMakesWithPaginationAsync(string search, int? page, string sort)
    {
        var makes = _context.VehicleMakes.AsQueryable();

        switch (sort)
        {
            case "Name desc":
                makes = makes.OrderByDescending(x => x.Name);
                break;
            default:
                makes = makes.OrderBy(x => x.Name);
                break;
        }

        return await makes.Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith(search) || search == null).ToPagedListAsync(page ?? 1, 5);
 }
}
```

After the review of my code, I was told that sorting, filtering and paging should be in separate classes that have interfaces. I implemented that in following way:

*Sorting:*

```
internal class Sorting : ISorting
{
    private readonly DbContext _context;

    public Sorting(DbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public IEnumerable<VehicleMake> SortMakes(string sort)
    {
        var makes = _context.VehicleMakes.AsQueryable();

        makes = sort == "Name desc" ? makes.OrderByDescending(x => x.Name) : makes.OrderBy(x => x.Name);
        return makes;
    }
}
```

*Paging:*

```
class Paging : IPaging
{
    private readonly ISorting _sorting;

    public Paging(DbContext context)
    {
        _sorting = new Sorting(context);
    }

    public async Task<IPagedList<VehicleMake>> GetPagedListOfSortedMakes(string search, int? page, string sort)
    {
        var sortedMakes = _sorting.SortMakes(sort).AsQueryable();
        return await sortedMakes.Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith(search) || search == null).ToPagedListAsync(page ?? 1, 5);
    }
}
```

And then in my service:

```
    public class VehicleMakeService : IVehicleMakeService
{
    private readonly DbContext _context;
    private readonly IPaging _paging;

    public VehicleMakeService(DbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
        _paging = new Paging(context);
    }

    public async Task<IPagedList<VehicleMake>> GetVehicleMakesWithPaginationAsync(string search, int? page, string sort)
    {
        return await _paging.GetPagedListOfSortedMakes(search, page, sort);
    }
}
```

This works well, but I'm not sure if I implemented this correctly. Is there a better (cleaner) way to do this?

Comment: This seems like a good question/discussion with your code reviewer. A good code reviewer acts as a mentor and coach and can provide direction and reasoning. Now as a matter of personal opinion, while there are cases where extracting a functionality into its own class/interface is necessary or desirable, I'm not sure this is one of those cases, or I would do it this way. But again, engage in a discussion with your teammate/architect/code-reviewer. And good luck!

Comment: You could try asking this question on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Any reason why you don't use https://github.com/dncuug/X.PagedList

This seems like a pretty good component.